# Get random process sample from autocorrelation function

Tags: matlab, random, process, correlation

I am to write a matlab function that returns samples of a random `process X(t)` as `X(n*delta_t)`, 
`t = 0,1,...,N` where `delta_t = 1/fs and fs = 2000Hz`.

I am completely stuck. I have the autocorrelation function `Rx = 5e^(-600|tau|)`. How do I get samples of the random process from this?

Comment: Is the random process Gaussian? If so, from the autocorrelation you can compute a linear time-invariant filter that applied to white Gaussian noise will give the desired output

Comment: It doesn't say. It's WSS but